# Splitting a dataframe into many smaller data frames evenly-ish

Tags: python, pandas, split, chunking

I have the following frame called df which is 65 items long.

```
   Name  Data
0  Name1 Data1
1  Name2 Data2
2  Name3 Data3
....
```

I want to split it into 30 data frames as evenly as possible.

So with a length of 65, I want there to be 5 frames of length 3 and 25 of length 2 (which adds up to 65)

I use the following function:

```
def chunk(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

n = 30 #number of files

length = len(df)

counter=0

for df_chunk in chunk(frame, int(length / n) + (length % n > 0)):
    counter+=1
    df_chunk.to_csv(f"path/to/file{counter}.csv")
```

But I only get 21 files which are, 3 in length and 1 file which is 2 in length instead of 5 files which are 3 in length and 25 which are 2 in length.

Anyone has any ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: `for k,d in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//30): print(k,d)`.

Comment: I get 3 frames, 30, 30 and 5 in length

Comment: sorry, replace  `//30` with `%30`.

Comment: okay it works now,

Comment: is there a way to get the k in k,d to start from 1? besides using my own counter

Comment: `np.arange(len(df))%30+1`?

Comment: do you mind quickly breaking down what this function does? thanks a lot for this answer by the way,

Comment: @anarchy It splits the input array as evenly as possible into  multiple subarrays as specified by us. So in your case it produces 5 frames of length 3 and 25 frames of length 2

Comment: no I meant, so I know groupby groups up rows where elements match, and I know arange creates a list of certain length. I don't understand how exactly the groupby function works together with it

Comment: @QuangHoang I guess using groupby here will disturb the order of rows in the result? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`np.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html), from the documentation it says:

> For an array of length `l` that should be split into n sections, it
>   returns `l % n` sub-arrays of size `l//n + 1` and the rest of size `l//n.`:

```
for counter, df_chunk in enumerate(np.array_split(df, 30), 1):
    df_chunk.to_csv(f"path/to/file{counter}.csv")
```